# cat multiple files into one using same amount of rows as file B from A B C

Tags: bash, shell, awk, count, paste

This is a strange question, I have been looking around and I wasn't able to find anything to match with what I wish to do.

What I'm trying to do is;

File A, File B, File C
5 Lines, 3 Lines, 2 Lines.

Join all files in one file matching the same amount of the file B
The output should be

File A, File B, File C
3 Lines, 3 Lines, 3 Lines.

So in file A I have to remove two lines, in File C i have to duplicate 1 line so I can match the same lines as file B.

I was thinking to do a count to see how many lines each file has first

```
count1=`wc -l FileA| awk '{print $1}'`
count2=`wc -l FileB| awk '{print $1}'`
count3=`wc -l FileC| awk '{print $1}'`

Then to do a gt then file B remove lines, else add lines.
```

But I have got lost as I'm not sure how to continue with this, I never seen anyone trying to do this.

Can anyone point me to an idea?

the output should be as per attached picture below;

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQTRV.png)
thanks.

Comment: Please, post the sample files with the expected output.

Comment: please post the expected input and output as **text**.

Comment: added as picture

Comment: What I don't understand from your picture: Do you want to output all the files side by side (as shown in the picture) or do you want to overwrite each file with its new content?

Comment: picture? no thanks for taking care of visually impared people, people who like to cut-n-paste and people who don't like to read multiple websites to answer a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. I have made `@` as a separator you could change it as per your need too.

```
paste -d'@' file1 file2 file3 |
awk -v file2_lines="$(wc -l < file2)" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="@"
}
FNR<=file2_lines{
  $1=$1?$1:prev_first
  $3=$3?$3:prev_third
  print
  prev_first=$1
  prev_third=$3
}'
```

---

---

***Example of running above code:***

Lets say following are Input_file(s):

```
cat file1
File1_line1
File1_line2
File1_line3
File1_line4
File1_line5

cat file2
File2_line1
File2_line2
File2_line3

cat file3
File3_line1
File3_line2
```

When I run above code in form of script following will be the output:

```
./script.ksh
File1_line1@File2_line1@File3_line1
File1_line2@File2_line2@File3_line2
File1_line3@File2_line3@File3_line2
```

Comment: I have used `@` as a output separator you could use `,` or whatever you need too in final output.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the first *n* lines of a files with the `head` command resp `sed`.
you can generate new lines with `echo`.

i'm going to use `sed`, as it allows in-place editing of a file (so you don't have to deal with temporary files):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

fix_numlines() {
  local filename=$1
  local wantlines=$2
  local havelines=$(grep -c . "${filename}")
  head -${wantlines} "${filename}"
  if [ $havelines -lt $wantlines ]; then
    for i in $(seq $((wantlines-havelines))); do echo; done
  fi
}

lines=$(grep -c . fileB)
fix_numlines fileA ${lines}
fix_numlines fileB ${lines}
fix_numlines fileC ${lines}
```

if you want columnated output, it's even simpler:

```sh
paste fileA fileB fileC | head -$(grep -c . fileB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another for GNU awk that outputs in columns:

```
$ gawk  -v seed=$RANDOM -v n=2 '  # n parameter is the file index number 
BEGIN {                           # ... which defines the record count
    srand(seed)                   # random record is printed when not enough records
}
{
    a[ARGIND][c[ARGIND]=FNR]=$0   # hash all data to a first
}
END {
    for(r=1;r<=c[n];r++)          # loop records
        for(f=1;f<=ARGIND;f++)    # and fields for below output
            printf "%s%s",((r in a[f])?a[f][r]:a[f][int(rand()*c[f])+1]),(f==ARGIND?ORS:OFS)
}' a b c                          # -v n=2 means the second file ie. b
```

Output:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c1
```

If you don't like the random pick of a record, replace `int(rand()*c[f])+1]` with `c[f]`.

```
$ gawk '                     # remember GNU awk only
NR==FNR {                    # count given files records
    bnr=FNR                 
    next
}
{
    print                    # output records of a b c
    if(FNR==bnr)             # ... up to bnr records
        nextfile             # and skip to next file
}
ENDFILE {                    # if you get to the end of the file
    if(bnr>FNR)              # but bnr not big enough
        for(i=FNR;i<bnr;i++) # loop some
            print            # and duplicate the last record of the file
}' b a b c                   # first the file to count then all the files to print
```

Comment: This works just fine, I only need to put them as columns on the new file, data should be a1,b1,b3 etc...

Comment: Updated a columnar output version.

Answer (score 0):

To make a file have `n` lines you can use the following function (usage: `toLength n file`). This omits lines at the end if the file is too long and repeats the last line if the file is too short.

```
toLength() {
    { head -n"$1" "$2"; yes "$(tail -n1 "$2")"; } | head -n"$1"
}
```

To set all files to the length of FileB and show them side by side use

```
n="$(wc -l < FileB)"
paste <(toLength "$n" FileA) FileB <(toLength "$n" FileC) | column -ts$'\t'
```

As observed by the user [umläute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282609/6770384) the side-by-side output makes things even easier. However, they used empty lines to pad out short files. The following solution repeats the last line to make short files longer.

```
stretch() {
    cat "$1"
    yes "$(tail -n1 "$1")"
}
paste <(stretch FileA) FileB <(stretch FileC) | column -ts$'\t' |
head -n"$(wc -l < FileB)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean way using `awk` where we read each file only a single time:

```
awk -v n=2 '
     BEGIN{ while(1) {
              for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i) {
                 if (b[i]=(getline tmp < ARGV[i])) a[i] = tmp
              }
              if (b[n]) for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i) print a[i] > ARGV[i]".new"
              else {break}
            }
          }'  f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
```

This works in the following way:

- the lead file is defined by the index `n`. Here we choose the lead file to be `f2`.
- We do not process the files in the standard read record, fields sequentially, but we use the `BEGIN` block where we read the files in parallel.
- We do an infinite loop `while(1)` where we will break out if the lead-file has no more input.
- Per cycle, we read a new line of each file using `getline`. If the file `i` has a new line, store it in `a[i]`, and set the outcome of `getline` into `b[i]`. If file `i` has reached its end, keep the last line in mind.
- Check the outcome of the lead file with `b[n]`. If we still read a line, print all the lines to the files `f1.new`, `f2.new`, ..., otherwise, break out of the infinite loop.